# PHP SimpleXMLElement xpath

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I am trying to perform a simple xpath lookup using an XML file from an HTTP POST.  I've been pulling my hair out, as this should work!!  Everything I've found thus far is a result of the namespace, but I have no namespace in this XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
 <bar>
  <name>Frank</name>
 </bar>
</foo>
```

Here is the simple code I'm using.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("php://input");
print_r($xml->xpath("//FOO/bar/name"));
```

This gives me an empty array!

```
Array
(
  [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
      (
      )
)
```

If I just do `print_r($xml->xpath("//foo"));` I see it has the data, but as soon as I try to get the value of name, I get nothing. :(

```
Array
(
  [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
      (
      [bar] => SimpleXMLElement Object
         (
              [name] => Frank
         )
      )
)
```

What is the deal??  Thank you!!

Comment: `FOO !== foo`. Thought I was cleaning up code with edit. CaSe sensitivity was actually your issue. Suggest close as a 'typo' question. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49436522/revisions

Comment: Looks like it's broken prior to 5.6.10: https://3v4l.org/sZX7P

Comment: If you really just want the value, you can do `$xml->xpath("//foo/bar/name")[0]->__toString()` as far back as 5.4.  That doesn't address the underlying issue of what you're trying to do for your current version though.

Comment: Some point in 5.5 behaviour changed. At 5.5.31 it started working again, like it did back in 5.4. So exact behaviour will depend on version.

Comment: I'm using 5.4.16 which is in the broken list.  Thanks Alex.  Patrick, thank you as well - that's similar to the posted answer.  Hate to be "weird" like that, but it's the version I'm using it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This gives me an empty array!

No it doesn't. Look closely at your output, and you will see that you have an array with one result in it, which is a `SimpleXMLElement` object.

Unfortunately, `print_r` doesn't handle `SimpleXMLElement` objects very well, and in some versions of PHP works better than others, so it doesn't accurately show you *what* `SimpleXMLElement` you have.

But your production code won't be relying on `print_r`, it will be relying on the actual content of that element, so let's see if we can get the content:

```
// Text content of an element is (string)$element
var_dump( (string)$first_result ); # string(5) "Frank"
// Render element back to XML
var_dump( $first_result->asXML() ); # string(18) "<name>Frank</name>"
```

This gives the right output in [all versions of PHP on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FV6kG). So there isn't actually a problem at all! :)